# Microsoft outlook 2010 computer based Synchrinize Error 0x80072F05?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, windows-server-2008, exchange-2010

Trying to synchronize the Offline Address Book to Microsoft Exchange offline address book.

The Error is: reported error (0x80072F05): ‘Unknown Error 0x80072F05’

Error message when you try to synchronize a Windows 7 on desktop computer using Microsoft outlook 2010 for Exchange 2010: "Synchronization failed"

Any idea how to solve this problem.

Client use windows 7 x64 for Microsoft outlook 2010  and

the windows server 2008 for Microsoft Exchange 2010 .

Answer (score 0):

You have a certificate issue. Here is what the error means:

```
C:\Users\André>err 0x80072F05
# anonymous HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), Facility 0x7, Code 0x2f05
# for hex 0x2f05 / decimal 12037
  ERROR_INTERNET_SEC_CERT_DATE_INVALID                           inetmsg.h
  ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_CERT_DATE_INVALID                         winhttp.h
  ERROR_INTERNET_SEC_CERT_DATE_INVALID                           wininet.h
# 3 matches found for "0x80072F05"
```